# updating/editing a field value for a devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added additional fields to a devise model and it doesn't seem like the value for the field is getting updated. I am using the default edit.html file provided by the devise library.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

I have a new field named phone_number, and I did something like

```
<%= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", hint: "leave it blank if you don't want to change it", required: false %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: false %>
<%= f.input :current_password, hint: "we need your current password to confirm your changes", required: true %>
<%= f.input :phone_number %>
```

Is there anything I can do to make it work? I am wondering where I can change how the view action/model behave. I currently do not have a separate controller for this model, if it matters.

Comment: Are you using Rails3?

Comment: Are you getting any error when you try to update the new attribute? Did you whitelist the new attribute in your strong param definition?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam I do not get any error, it simply stays with the value that I put in through database. And I am not sure what whitelisting the new attribute in strong param definition means. I just looked up strong param, and is it correct that it belongs to a controller?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam nice it worked. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Rails 4, you need to whitelist the additional devise attributes in order to mass assign it's value. Add something like this in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:method_name) do |u|
      u.permit(:attr1, :attr2) # add the new attribute in this list
    end
  end
```

You can see the [documentation here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md#strong-parameters).